# How to animate using css3 in angular based on click?

Tags: html, css, angular, animation

I have a span which uses bootstrap icon. I am trying to fade out and fade in the same element (span) on click, but toggle the class(icon).

I have a boolean variable named `showLegend`, based on it's value, I want to animate the span. I know that it works when element initializes, if I give it as a class. However, I want to trigger the animation on each click (i.e., when toggleTrendLegend() function is called, as shown in plunker). Kindly let me know how can I do that?

`animate-fade` class is what I want to trigger on each click.

On a side note, I do not want to use Angular Animation as it gets heavy for simple animations.

I have created a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/uMH0H7HgaUCHlv9BJVL9?p=preview)

This is the reference code:

```
<div class="show-hide">

   <span (click)="toggleTrendLegend()" [class]="showLegend == true ? 'animate-fade glyphicon adjust-eye glyphicon-eye-close' : 'glyphicon adjust-eye glyphicon-eye-open'"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this :

Using `class.yourClass`

```
<span (click)="showLegend = !showLegend" [class.animate-fade.glyphicon-adjust-eye.glyphicon-eye-close]="showLegend" [class.animate-fade.glyphicon-adjust-eye.glyphicon-eye-close]="!showLegend"></span>
```

Using `ngClass`

```
<span (click)="showLegend = !showLegend" [ngClass]="{'animate-fade glyphicon adjust-eye glyphicon-eye-close' : showLegend, 'glyphicon adjust-eye glyphicon-eye-open': !showLegend}"></span>
```

With animations : [please refer to the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

In all cases, don't forgot the animation !

```
transition: all 275ms ease-in-out;
```